# Adding a sub-menu in navigation bar (Wordpress)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm new to Wordpress Development and I read some discussions but I didn't really understand what I'm suppose to do. I made the custom navigation bar for my website but I an unable to make a sub-menu for my navbar. I know I'm suppose to make a walker class but I don't really understand the functionalities behind it. Any help is appreciated it. Here is my HTML code:

[image: HTML Code Here]

```
    <!-- NAVBAR
    ================================================== -->
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div><!-- navbar-header -->

                <!-- If the menu (WP admin area) is not set, then the "menu_class" is applied to "container". In other words, it overwrites the "container_class". Ref: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_nav_menu-menu_class-usage-bug?replies=4 -->

                <?php
                    wp_nav_menu( array(

                        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                        'container'         => 'nav',
                        'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
                        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'

                    ) );
                ?>

            </div><!-- container -->

        </div><!-- navbar -->

    </div><!-- navbar-wrapper -->

</header>
```

Comment: But you can directly link the pages in wordpress menu.. just create all pages in wordpress.. then go to appearance > menus .. create new menu and select all pages what u want in Navigation

Comment: This is not how you add menu in WordPress. Read here for more info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear but I'm converting a static HTML page -> dynamic page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this three simple steps for wp-bootstrap-navwalker. https://docs.google.com/document/d/161g7nkL5pFXeeZcdXtDhUc6zCSvP6wEdU7ztONNiLAY/edit